# ASP.NET ProtocolViolationException - Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why will **req.GetRequestStream().Close();** cause "**ProtocolViolationException**  - Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type." The code snippet is from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/XmlPost.aspx). Thanks.

```
        WebRequest req = null;
        WebResponse rsp = null;
        try
        {
            string fileName = "Login.xml";
            string uri = "http://localhost/api/login";
            req = WebRequest.Create(uri);

            //req.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy(); // Enable if using proxy
            req.Method = "POST";        // Post method
            req.ContentType = "text/xml";     // content type

            // Wrap the request stream with a text-based writer
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());

            // Write the XML text into the stream
            writer.WriteLine(this.GetTextFromXMLFile(fileName));
            writer.Close();

            // Send the data to the webserver
            rsp = req.GetResponse();

        }
        catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            LOG.Error(webEx.StackTrace.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LOG.Error(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (req != null) req.GetRequestStream().Close();
            if (rsp != null) rsp.GetResponseStream().Close();
        }
```

Comment: How is this related to ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `req.ContentType = application/xml` instead of `text/xml`?

Comment: I have a similar problem and `req.ContentType = application/xml` doesn't solve it.