# Posting XML over HTTP - Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, http

So I've got this code, which ideally must not change. On my test site, this code executes fine and posts new data into the database. But on the live site I get the below error. Can anyone advise on what this might be?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebRequest req = null;
    WebResponse rsp = null;
    //  try
    //  {
    string fileName = Server.MapPath("ExampleXML.xml");
    string uri = "http://XXX/api/index.aspx";

    req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    //req.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy(); // Enable if using proxy
    req.Method = "POST";        // Post method
    req.ContentType = "text/xml";     // content type
    // Wrap the request stream with a text-based writer
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
    // Write the XML text into the stream
    writer.WriteLine(this.GetTextFromXMLFile(fileName));
    writer.Close();
    // Send the data to the webserver
    rsp = req.GetResponse();

    //  }
    //  catch (WebException webEx)
    //  {

    //  }
    //  catch (Exception ex)
    //  {

    // }
    // finally
    //{
    if (req != null) req.GetRequestStream().Close();
    if (rsp != null) rsp.GetResponseStream().Close();
    //}
}
```

The error on the live site only is:-

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.

Line 47:         // finally
Line 48:         //{
Line 49:         if (req != null) req.GetRequestStream().Close();
Line 50:         if (rsp != null) rsp.GetResponseStream().Close();
Line 51:         //}
```

But I am sending a POST request, and this works on my test site, just not the live site. I've ensured the code is copied over and all the files exist.

Why would this code work on one and not the other?

Cheers,
Mike.

Comment: Check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981564/cannot-send-a-content-body-with-this-verb-type) should answer your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6508906/3232345

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue. The same error is still present in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, the issue here was a URL re-write in the web.config, which was set to replace .aspx with a /. This stoppped the XML data being sent through and resulted in the above erro.